How to find the Residue of $f(z) = \frac{9z^2+1}{z[1+\cosh(\frac{\pi}{z})]}$ in zero.
I don't know how to deal with the singularity z=0 in this function:

Determine all the singularities of $f(z) = \frac{9z^2+1}{z[1+\cosh(\frac{\pi}{z})]}$ and then compute the integral along $|z|=2$ counterclockwise.

I found that $z=\infty$ is a pole of order 1 and that $z_k=\frac{1}{(2k+1)i}$ are poles of order 2 (for $k\in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$).
But I don't know how to deal with the singularity in $z=0$.
It seems an essential singularity, but how can I find the Laurent Expansion?
I tried to split $\frac{9z^2+1}{z[1+\cosh(\frac{\pi}{z})]} =\frac{9z}{1+\cosh(\frac{\pi}{z})}+\frac{1}{z[1+\cosh(\frac{\pi}{z})]}$ and then by expanding the $\cosh $ I find:
$$\frac{9z}{1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\frac{\pi}{z})^{2n}}{(2n)!}}$$ and similarly
$$\frac{1}{z+z\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\frac{\pi}{z})^{2n}}{(2n)!}}$$
but I don't know how to continue in order to get $Res(f,0)$. Any Hint?

Use the half angle identity to rewrite the expression in the denominator
$$1+\cosh\left(\frac{\pi}{z}\right) = 2\cosh^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2z}\right)$$
The sequence of points $z_n = \frac{\pm i}{2n+1}$ defines a list of points where the function has poles of order $2$. They cluster around zero arbitrarily close, therefore zero is not an isolated singularity of this function, let alone an essential singularity. The concept of a Laurent series, and hence a residue, does not exist here.

Thank you! I now see they are poles of order 2. I used the definition to compute that they were poles of order 1 but probably I get them wrong, so I'll try to redo them.  but what if I want to compute $\int_{|z|=2} f(z) dz$?

@JamesCats have you identified which poles exist within the region bounded by the curve? If so, sum them all up.

Ok maybe I get it, since all the (infinitely many) poles $z_k$ are inside ${|z|=2}$ we can use the Residue at infinity to compute the integral i.e. $\int_{|z|=2} f(z) dz = 2\pi i Res(f,\infty) $
